# SFTP over reverse SSH tunnel?

Tags: ssh, kde, ssh-tunneling, sftp, dolphin

I want to SFTP to a remote computer that is behind NAT. I can't modify the NAT router, so I have set up a reverse SSH tunnel using a middleman server.

Here's what my SSH tunnel looks like:

```
laptop--->nat--->middleman<--nat<--desktop
```

The full details are here: 
[Remote desktop over SSH reverse tunnel to replace TeamViewer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82386/remote-desktop-over-ssh-reverse-tunnel-to-replace-teamviewer)

I am currently using SSH and VNC over this tunnel.

**How do I use SFTP over the tunnel?**

I assume the command will look something like

```
sftp://localhost:port
```

SSH login is via ***key pair only (no password)*** so we need to consider that in the solution. And I use KDE, so I need to get this working with Dolphin file manager. I've heard that setting up SFTP authentication in Dolphin can be a pain...

I'll be running Dolphin on the laptop and connecting to the file system on the desktop like this.

```
laptop(SFTP client)--->nat--->middleman<--nat<--desktop(SFTP server)
```

P.S. I would consider sshfs too, if that would be easier. I assume it won't because I don't have a domain name or IP address for the server.

Comment: you can use FileZilla with sftp and port forwarding. Check out: https://superuser.com/a/1286681/141314

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this is a prerequesite (at least for me): 
[Remote desktop over SSH reverse tunnel to replace TeamViewer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82386/remote-desktop-over-ssh-reverse-tunnel-to-replace-teamviewer)

The reverse SSH tunnel looks like this:

```
laptop(SFTP client)--->nat--->middleman<--nat<--desktop(SFTP server)
```

On `laptop` edit ~/.ssh/config and add this:

```
Host SftpToDesktop
  HostName localhost
  Port %p
  User admin
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my_id_rsa
```

Then, with an existing SSH leg from laptop to middleman established already (as per above link), do the following:

```
$ ssh -fNL 1234:localhost:1234 -i ~/.ssh/some_id_rsa admin@middleman.com
```

Finally, open Dolphin (if using KDE like me) and enter this location:

```
sftp://SftpToDesktop:1234
```